# how we can change the title alignment in a form

Tags: javascript, extjs4, title

I m creating a form in layout.I want to align the title in centre. example: Registration.
Here is a simple code.

```
{
    // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
    title: 'Settings',
    region:'east',
    xtype: 'panel',
    margins: '0 0 0 0',
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true, 
    split: true,   // make collapsible
    id: 'egion-container',
    layout: 'fit'
 }
```

i want that title "Settings" in center

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change label Align in extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851755/how-to-change-label-align-in-extjs)

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions. `titleAlign: center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply wrap title inside a div tag and do whatever you want :

```
{
    // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
    title: '<div style="text-align:center;">Settings</div>',
    region:'east',
    xtype: 'panel',
    margins: '0 0 0 0',
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true, 
    split: true,   // make collapsible
    id: 'egion-container',
    layout: 'fit'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the docs, there's a config called [`titleAlign`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel).